# Error with count up when use setInterval and clearInterval

Tags: javascript, html

I use countTime function for incrementing timer, I have 1 function gameStart to initialize game structures and assign variable totalSecond = 0 and variable timeStart = setInterval(countTime, 1000). I have a button that when clicked it will run the function gameStart. When I run the code for the first time, everything is fine, but when I press the button many times with the newGame event, it increases the time very quickly. I have to clearInteval when I lose the game so time can stop. Thank for help me

```
function countTimer() {
        totalSeconds++;
        var hour = Math.floor(totalSeconds /3600);
        var minute = Math.floor((totalSeconds - hour*3600)/60);
        var seconds = totalSeconds - (hour*3600 + minute*60);
        if(hour < 10)
        hour = "0"+hour;
        if(minute < 10)
        minute = "0"+minute;
        if(seconds < 10)
        seconds = "0"+seconds;
        document.getElementById("countUp").innerHTML = hour + ":" + minute + ":" + seconds;
 }

function gameStart() {
    timerVar = setInterval(countTimer, 1000);
    totalSeconds = 0;
    rows = parseInt(document.getElementById("rows").value);
    cols = parseInt(document.getElementById("cols").value);
    mineCount = parseInt(document.getElementById("mines").value);
    rows = rows > 10 ? rows : 10;
    cols = cols > 10 ? cols : 10;
    mCount = mCount > 10 ? mCount : 10;
    openedCells=0;
    initBoard();
    initHTML();
}
```

Comment: "but when I press the button many times with the newGame event" do you have global state for these events? You need global state because its "one" game. You dont want multiple instances of the game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setInterval functions never expire until you call clearInterval. In your case, every time you run gameStart, a new interval is created that counts up.
You are left with multiple intervals, making the timer go up quicker and quicker.

A quick fix would be to declare timerVar outside the Function, then clear and re-make it every time gameStart is called.

```
timerVar = setInterval(()=>{},1000) // Empty interval
function gameStart() {
  clearInterval(timerVar)
  timerVar = setInterval(countTimer, 1000);
  totalSeconds = 0;
```

I'm unable to test this at the moment, but it should work.

Comment: Yay! @NguyễnKhang, do you mind if you mark this answer as correct? It'll help me help more people.

Comment: i will correct answer